# How to automatically click a submit button on a web page every few minutes?

Tags: javascript

There is a button on a web page that I have to click to refresh my data. I would like to write a script that automatically clicks that refresh button every few minutes even when I am not on that page or the computer is turned off. This is how the source code of that button looks like:

`<button class="refresh-data" type="submit" ng-click="refreshdata()"`

Maybe I have to mention that I have to be logged in in order to click that button. I am new to this, so my question is, if this is possible with javascript? Or is there any tool that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Well since a click is only a call to a function you could use setInterval() to call the function that you've put on your submit like so:
    setInterval(()=>{myFunction();},1000); But you can not do it automatically with your computer turned off. You have to calculate the clicks made once you go to your webpage again. (or do a cron task if you've hosted the webpage)

Comment: do you own that web page or is it a third party?

Comment: no, I do not own that web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger a click event every second using javascript like so

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector('button.refresh-data').click()
}, 1000)
```

Now that said clicking on the button only means calling a function, so you could also call it directly

```js
setInterval(refreshdata, 1000)
```

I'm not sure why you would want to attempt triggering this when the page does not exist or when your computer is off, as by definition the page (and your code) does not exist at this time. If some routine logic needs to happen that will likely be done in your backend codebase, independently from your frontend application.